# matplotlib.animation not working

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

So i've been trying to generate a dynamically updating plot that shows me several data sets as a scatter plot. I have two identically sized lists col1 and col2 containing lists in each position. not all of these lists are equally long but `len(col1[i]) = len(col2[i])`.

So this is what i've tried so far:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)    
def animate(i):
        x=col1[i]
        y=col2[i]
        ax.clear()
        ax.scatter(x, y)
a = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

When I do `scatter(col1[0],col2[0])` I see the following:

[image: out1]

and this is the first image i want to see, then the corresponding for `scatter(col1[1],col2[1])` and so on.

And this is what I get every time:

[image: Output]

I notice the program is still running so I suppose the plot might still be updating with the same "image".

Am I missing something in my code?

EDIT: The second image is also what I get when I scatter plot everything together

Comment: Does the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470324/first-set-of-scatter-plot-data-remains-on-the-graph-during-animation-with-pyth work for you?

Comment: Oho, a bunch of examples now give `AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'restore_region'`.              

However, these still work:
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/animation/random_data.html

so try adapting one of those.

Comment: ... and the other is an open issue according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216520/mac-osx-attributeerror-figurecanvasmac-object-has-no-attribute-restore-reg

Comment: It was not a canvas issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code is correct, I presume the image was the interval between points updating in the figurewas too fast and thus the second image is all it showed.

fixed by setting the interval option to 50 msecs in

`a = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50)`

(Literally replacing the line for this one fixed it.)